# Is Move or Die on console?

Tags: move-or-die

I've seen some live-streamers play it, so I wanted to get it, but I want to play it on my XBOX One or PS4. Are they on those?

Comment: @Frank Not exactly, it said, out on PC, Mac, and Linux, and it never said anything about it not being on console.

Comment: And any amount of googling it still would have told you. This shows absolutely no effort to answer your question before asking.

Comment: @Frank I googled Move or Die, went on the website, and , and it never said anything about it not being on console. Case closed. Stop commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it's currently only on PC

As per the website:

> OUT NOW on Steam for PC, Mac & Linux

Sorry!

Comment: Ok, so if my friends wanted to play, would they have to buy it also?

Comment: @MrLemon It wouldn't let me mark it as an answer for seven minutes, and I have work. I'm not on every every second of the day.